# How to send email on form submission using django forms?

Tags: django, email, django-forms, sendmail

Prior to sending mails on actual website, I'm running a small test Django local SMTP server:
I have to congifure these settings in **settings.py**. But where do I put it?

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = '1025'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Then how do I proceed? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put these in your `settings.py` file. You can put the below settings anywhere in your `settings.py` file.

**settings.py**

```
...

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'  # since you are using a gmail account
EMAIL_PORT = 587  # Gmail SMTP port for TLS
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True    
...
```

**local_settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your_username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_gmail_password'
```

Then to send an email, you can use Django's `send_email()`.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('My Subject', 'My message', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Mail is then sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` settings in your `settings.py` file. The `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` settings, if set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the `EMAIL_USE_TLS` settings control whether a secure connection is used.

**Signature of send_email():**

> send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list,
>   fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None,
>   connection=None, html_message=None)

**Note:** You can put your gmail account information in a `local_settings.py` and add this `local_settings` to git-ignore. Then include this local_settings in your `settings.py`. This way only you would be able to see your `local_settings`.

Comment: is that all required? will it send a mail from the from address (from@example.com)? isnt logging in required to send mail then?

Comment: if i am sending mail from my gmail account, what do i give in EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD?

Comment: You need to define `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` for authenticating into the SMTP server defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do I define them as? And how do I start/use SMTP server?

Comment: Okay, thank you but what do I have in local_settings.py? And what about running SMTP server?

Comment: In your `local_settings`, you can put your Gmail credentials. After defining all the settings, you just need to call the `send_email`  function to send mails.

Comment: okok and calling the function directly connects to SMTP server right?

Comment: and 'from@example.com' and 'username@gmail.com ' are the same right?

Comment: Yes Django will itself create a connection with Google's SMTP server. Also,  'from@example.com' and 'username@gmail.com ' are the same.