# Django: send email on form submition

Tags: django

I need to send an email after user submits a form on my page (this is still in development, but it'll be in production soon).

I've read this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334029/how-to-send-email-on-form-submission-using-django-forms) but after my form is submitted I'm not reciving any email (I've used my personal email as the sender and the receiver, for testing).

**What I need to modify?**

**PLUS:** *How to send images on emails? Any tutorial on this? I need to send professional emails after form submition.*

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'  # since you are using a gmail account
EMAIL_PORT = 587  # Gmail SMTP port for TLS
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'oma.oma@gmail.com' #Not my actual email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MyPassword' #Not my actual password
```

**views.py:**

```
# here we are going to use CreateView to save the Third step ModelForm
class StepThreeView(CreateView):
    form_class = StepThreeForm
    template_name = 'main_app/step-three.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.tamanios = self.request.session.get('tamanios')  # get tamanios from session
        form.instance.cantidades = self.request.session.get('cantidades')  # get cantidades from session
        del self.request.session['cantidades']  # delete cantidades value from session
        del self.request.session['tamanios']  # delete tamanios value from session
        self.request.session.modified = True
        return super(StepThreeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**form.py:**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class StepThreeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    instrucciones = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = TamaniosCantidades
        fields = ('imagenes', 'instrucciones')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StepThreeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['instrucciones'].required = False

    def send_email(self):
        send_mail('Django Test', 'My message', 'oma.oma@gmail.com',
                  ['oma.oma@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: It seems that you are not calling the send_email method of your form anywhere...

Comment: @ivissani how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `save` method like this in your Last Form:

```
 class StepThreeForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def save(self, commit=True):
          instance = super(StepThreeForm, self).save(commit=commit)
          self.send_email()
          return instance

       def send_email(self):
           image = self.cleaned_data.get('imagenes', None)
           msg = EmailMessage(
              'Hello',
              'Body goes here',
              'from@example.com',
              ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
              headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
           )

           msg.content_subtype = "html"

           if image:
             mime_image = MIMEImage(image.read())
             mime_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
             msg.attach(mime_image)
           msg.send()
```

You can check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787755/django-how-to-send-html-emails-with-embedded-images) for more details on how to send image from Django

Comment: There are unsolve references in your `send_email` method: `EmailMessage` and `MIMEImage`. So tried only updating the save method and got this error:  `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: @OmarGonzales updated my answer, missed the return statement from save method

Comment: tried the updated answer, but getting: `Could not guess image MIME subtype` even I'm not attaching any image.

Comment: instead of `msg.attach(mime_image)`, maybe you can use `msg.attach_file(obj.imagenes.path)` and pass this obj in the `send_email` method like `self.send_email(obj=instance)`.  For documentation, please see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects . Update the method signature as well `def send_email(self, obj)` :)